# Conflicts between addons contexts?

Tags: python, add-on

Something i have write in a addon script influences the behaviour of another addon. I dont know why, but i am presuming this is due to the context.
The other addon behaviour is changing even if i do not execute my addon (but just if the addon is installed).
How to avoid that ? Is there a way to define my own context class ?

Edit 1:

The other addon is [Avastar (for Second Life)](https://www.avalab.org/avastar/).
The "bad behaviour" is that using fitted bones sliders in Avastar does not work correctly (mesh is curiously shifted to the right). This does not happen if my addon is not registered (and with the same mesh).

Edit 2: more generally, how to create a context which can be based on another class than those provided in `bpy.types`?

Comment: Please elaborate, what is the other addon, what is the 
"behaviour" that is being influenced? Some code would be handy too...?   By addon installed to you mean registered? Not sure jumping to defining your own context class is the way to go.

Comment: The "bad behaviour" is that using fitted bones sliders in Avastar does not work correctly (mesh is curiously shifted to the right). This does not happen if my addon is not registered (and with the same mesh).

Comment: You can paste code directly into http://www.pasteall.org/69992/python  Don't have Avastar to test against.  Could see if gaia is on #blendercoders irc.freenode.net  Does the Avastar addon have any of the scene properties you've defined `scene.sourceArmature` for example?  Also suggest editing your question with the above details.

Comment: I have searched for my properties names in the blender addons folders : no hit, except my addon. But can you confirm that conflicts are possible ?

Comment: Not sure re conflicts, but would be a very very last resort I'd go to .. (defining my own context class) Have a look at the avastar code that is run when the fitted bones slider values are changed, and what are the properties of the sliders etc etc.   Drivers?, update method?